# Python - Scraped Text Results to a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am working on my academic assignments and not good with python, just a beginner.

I scraped product "names" and "prices".
Questions:

1- I want to create two lists of the results from the output. Using list() command doesn't help and breaks each name into its alphabets and then creates the list, which is not what I am trying to achieve.

2- Is there a better of scraping the product name and its price from ebay and get results in a list containing names and corresponding prices along with the specification features, such as mobiles' specs?

I will be grateful to you for your advice.
Thanks.

```
productName = list(productNameElement.find('h3').text)
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code. Right now it is not entirely clear what you are asking and where exactly you are stuck codewise.

Comment: Please share your code with question so we can help you.

Comment: Can you share an URL/relevant html?

Comment: Also, be very clear on what scraped info you are after. Specification features could be quite broad. Share your code as well so we understand what approach you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
names = productNameElement.find('h3').text
names = names.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method and change it into Your code

```
data=['a','p','p','l','e']
list=("").join(data)
print(list)
```

Output:

apple

Answer (score 0):

Why Reinventing the wheel ? It is probably better to use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) module to properly soup an HTML file.

Something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc="<html>...Your html code ... <h3>myproductname_1</h3> still your html code to soup...<h3>myproductname_2</h3>...</html>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
product_list=[]
for productName in soup.find_all('h3'):
    print(productName.get_text())
    product_list.append(productName.get_text())
print(product_list)
```

which give you:

```
myproductname_1
myproductname_2
[u'myproductname_1', u'myproductname_2']
```

Comment: 'pip install beautifulsoup4' to install beautifulsoup